# Unsure what int regs = 0, i, *regs means

Tags: c

I'm maintaining and extending the functionality of a diagnostic test suite, and this fragment of code comes up multiple times and I'm not sure what it does:

```
int ret = 0, i, *reg;
int size = sizeof(Regs)/sizof(Reg);
for(i = 0; i<size; i++) {
    reg= (uint*)Regs[i].Number;
    *reg=0;
}
return ret;
```

Where i is  looping variable, and reg is a pointer to a 32-bit int (Number being the address to that 32-bit int). This particular test clears the registers, but is it meant to change ret?

EDIT: I guess my question was a bit ambiguous, I am wondering specifically what the fragment:

```
int ret = 0, i, *regs;
```

Does, or why it is valid.

Comment: ret looks like to be there only to keep trace of which value will be returned, just in case you want to change it before it ends

Comment: Casting to `uint*` and then assigning to an `int*` is probably a mistake -- not sure if it's a copying error or if the original code is dodgy.

Comment: I am not the original writer of the code, but I'm fairly certain an unsigned 0 and a signed 0 should have the same representation.

Comment: @Steve, zero is zero for both `uint` and `int` =).

Comment: There are representations with positive and negative zeros for signed ints.

Comment: All true but beside the point :-) The conversion through `uint*` is useless, and is only allowed in C because it has such a lax type system, it would be forbidden in C++. This is all assuming that `uint` is `unsigned int` -- if it's something else then that's a whole different mistake!

Comment: I would not use a cast at all. I would use the correct type for `reg` or directly assign `*(Regs[i].Number) = 0;` without an intermediate pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int ret = 0, i, *reg;`

defines three variables: an `int` called `ret`, an `int` called `i` and an `int*` called `reg`. Only `ret` is initialized (to `0`).

The reason is that the grammar for a declaration (slightly simplified) is:

```
declaration: 
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list[_opt_]
init-declarator-list:
    init-declarator
    init-declarator-list , init-declarator
init-declarator:
    declarator
    declarator = initializer
```

Here the declaration-specifiers are just `int`, then we have an init-declarator list consisting of three init-declarators. One of them has an initializer and the other two don't. The declarator `*reg` defines a "pointer-to-whatever-type-the-declaration-specifiers-say". See 6.7 "Declarations" in the standard for the gory details (and the bits I left out of the grammar above).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think you are right. Assuming that Regs is an array of Reg objects, then it zeros out what each Reg.Number is pointing to, then returns 0. This seems like a reasonable thing to do if the codebase follows the paradigm of returning a status code in which case 0 most often means success.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I figured. So why exactly is int ret = 0, i, *regs; a valid line in C? I'm still not exactly sure how that works.

Comment: @ardentsonata, `int` is the type of everything in the line. `ret` is an int that gets initialized to zero, `i` is an int, and `*regs` is an int -- which makes `regs` an int pointer. Make sense?

Comment: `int ret = 0, i, *regs;`
is equivalent to
`int ret = 0;
int i;
int *regs;`

Answer (score 0):

No, `ret` will always be zero. This function just clears some `uint`s pointed to by structs in the array `Regs`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like always returning 0. Unless I am seeing only a portion of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

My personal view:

```
int ret = 0, i, *reg; 
int size = sizeof(Regs)/sizof(Reg); 
for(i = 0; i<size; i++) 
{
     reg= (uint*)Regs[i].Number;
     *reg=0;
} 
return ret;
```

The line `int ret = 0, i, *reg;` is equivalent to

```
int ret;
ret = 0; //return value, if nothing changes it while running the sub, the return is (positive) as every C routine should do
int i; // i is what it is, no initialisation is performed
int* reg; //reg is what it is, no initialisation is performed.
```

The line `int size = sizeof(Regs)/sizof(Reg);`  defines `size` as the atomic dimension between a buffer called `Regs` and its elementary data field of type `Reg`. Used to iterate over the structure itself (NOTE: in C it is not necessary that Regs is a buffer/array/stream, it is just necesssary that it is bigger than regs in terms of Sizeof.

The `for` loop is zeroing n byte in each single iteration starting from the position of Number field inside Reg (supppose `Number` is 32bits = 4 bytes long integer from byte 4 to byte 7 inside `Reg`).

The (uint*) cast is normal in C with respect the more readable (uint*) because when dealing with memory a simple (uint) is possibly not enough to span the whole addresssable heap. Rarely I've found (int*) casts to iterate over the heap.

Finally, after nothing has failed (nothing can fail the code in this case as ret is not even used) the return value is 0 = positive return.

To better explain what is done in the for loop, suppose Regs is a structure containing 4 Reg istances in a row (some kind of array) and each Reg is 32 byte wide, and the second field (bytes from 4 to 7) is called `Number` ( a 32 bits integer field for example).
Byte by byte visualisation of the memory (in DECIMAL format for ease of use and read) before and after the run of the for loop could be:

```
before:     111910460 §     721672678 §     1941200806 §    -1183627007 §   1586684153 §    1875498315 §    1260999030 §    1325944862 §    1065932391 §    1844134883 §    1605637187 §    -1318663956 §   233262241 §     1220589880 §    1712611369 §    -2095694326 §   -1982972241 §   1536475566 §    1550414594 §    60661453 §      1920891323 §    1052971320 §    151058183 §     -693448823 §    -763585993 §    -1546059240 §   -638901203 §    1592652624 §    -26126893 §     359938920 §     730403663 §     -2119128428 §   22506289 §      329168535 §     1888110366 §    -1324425487 §   -2128177580 §   -1447190387 §   -2102707104 §   -834692095 §    233601466 §     -2368015 §      -1247566469 §   -496146592 §    1399945760 §    -433672213 §    -1874762262 §   -240141582 §    1361991330 §    -2100310671 §   -1716316415 §   1113810979 §    837914061 §     -2004720198 §   -499664162 §    -581537344 §    -1876582939 §   -855186203 §    -477447744 §    609476093 §     -1551962613 §   1342130125 §    -1245085596 §   70042099 §      853203728 §     -1216264601 §   -821207587 §    -663767272 §    1811963624 §    -1359626002 §   587239161 §     412800157 §     1308828835 §    -484000995 §    1196157114 §    1554729984 §    -588907472 §    -862275327 §    2141670903 §    -496863553 §    -1461319540 §   2011880048 §    724185989 §     -523083707 §    535075127 §     -1252818631 §   -1535682266 §   1731550626 §    -1513281783 §   2056573089 §    542455754 §     -1663652432 §   209157746 §     -917714063 §    -62336558 §     -335893804 §    -455431912 §    -1338920623 §   966843505 §     698158966 §     -1748732016 §   -710422429 §    429351988 §     1404039358 §    1828069719 §    -1849911876 §   -1756314151 §   1046003361 §    -1124626131 §   422202 §        608265685 §     1538084062 §    -1342247255 §   1734342148 §    -2095965518 §   544674987 §     -12582890 §     1365311130 §    1104188373 §    688131395 §     -1615783097 §   755406204 §     -151161805 §    1955152994 §    -427907710 §    700996102 §    
after:  111910460 §     721672678 §     1941200806 §    -1183627007 §   0 §             0 §             0 §             0 §             1065932391 §    1844134883 §    1605637187 §    -1318663956 §   233262241 §     1220589880 §    1712611369 §    -2095694326 §   -1982972241 §   1536475566 §    1550414594 §    60661453 §      1920891323 §    1052971320 §    151058183 §     -693448823 §    -763585993 §    -1546059240 §   -638901203 §    1592652624 §    -26126893 §     359938920 §     730403663 §     -2119128428 §   22506289 §      329168535 §     1888110366 §    -1324425487 §   0 §             0 §             0 §             0 §             233601466 §     -2368015 §      -1247566469 §   -496146592 §    1399945760 §    -433672213 §    -1874762262 §   -240141582 §    1361991330 §    -2100310671 §   -1716316415 §   1113810979 §    837914061 §     -2004720198 §   -499664162 §    -581537344 §    -1876582939 §   -855186203 §    -477447744 §    609476093 §     -1551962613 §   1342130125 §    -1245085596 §   70042099 §      853203728 §     -1216264601 §   -821207587 §    -663767272 §    0 §             0 §             0 §             0 §             1308828835 §    -484000995 §    1196157114 §    1554729984 §    -588907472 §    -862275327 §    2141670903 §    -496863553 §    -1461319540 §   2011880048 §    724185989 §     -523083707 §    535075127 §     -1252818631 §   -1535682266 §   1731550626 §    -1513281783 §   2056573089 §    542455754 §     -1663652432 §   209157746 §     -917714063 §    -62336558 §     -335893804 §    -455431912 §    -1338920623 §   966843505 §     698158966 §     0 §             0 §             0 §             0 §             1828069719 §    -1849911876 §   -1756314151 §   1046003361 §    -1124626131 §   422202 §        608265685 §     1538084062 §    -1342247255 §   1734342148 §    -2095965518 §   544674987 §     -12582890 §     1365311130 §    1104188373 §    688131395 §     -1615783097 §   755406204 §     -151161805 §    1955152994 §    -427907710 §    700996102 §
```